# What are alternatives to JUnit's assertEquals() method in order to see in the test report which fields of objects differed on comparison?

Tags: java, junit

I have a lot of automated tests written in Java on JUnit and often I use `assertEquals(java.lang.String message, java.lang.Object expected, java.lang.Object actual)`.
If you compare primitive types then in case of assert failure it is clearly visible in the test report that values were different, e.g. in case of 2 integers comparison. But when you compare two complex objects then the output of the test can be quite cluttered. Even if you have properly override the `toString()` method which will list all fields with all values the output would be long. Imagine having a class:

```
public class Invoice {

    private LocalDate invoiceDate;
    private String invoiceNumber;
    private InvoiceType invoiceType;
    private InvoiceStatus invoiceStatus;
    private String mediaPlanner;
    private String yourReference;
    private String responsiblePerson;
    private Brand advertiser;
    private MediaAgency mediaAgency;
    private Set<InvoiceRow> invoiceRows;
    .....
```

The `InvoiceRow` is also quite a complex object with a lot of its own fields. So if I put these all fields into the `toString()` implementation and the assert fails then JUnit will output quite a long message which will be not very easy to read by eyes in order to see that in one object the invoice type, for example, was incorrect.

Is there some tools/approaches to improve this in a way that my test report will show a rather clear and concise output in case when comparison fails?
Maybe I should use some other test frameworks which has more tooling/features?

Comment: seeing as you are the one setting the different values, do you need to have an additional test? anyway, you can always write your own method where, if an assert fails, you set a custom message

Comment: @Stultuske I am not the one setting different values. I have automation with Selenium webdriver which retrieves fields of the invoice in this case from web browser UI, then composes the actual Invoice instance from them and only then there is an assert which compares the expected instance from the test setup fixture with this actual instance obtained from UI.
But all these details are really not important in my question.
When an assertEquals fails I have no info if it fails because `invoiceDate` fields differ or some other fields differ. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: clarifies, yes. but it also shows that your tests are ... flawed. how are you going to test what should be there, if you don't know what is put there in the first place?

Comment: @Stlultuske I have mentioned that my expected instance is set up in the test fixture. So don't jump to conclusions too fast. To save your time: at the test start I create an invoice instance with particular values, let's call it `expectedInvoice`. Then test creates this invoice in UI and saves it. Then it opens it and retrieves fields from UI and constructs another instance, let's call it `actualInvoice`. Then assert compares `expectedInvoice` and `actualInvoice`. So I think this is not flawed and xactly how it should be. In fact I simplified the flow for you, in reality it is more complex.

Comment: If you're writing tests, then the tests should already know what they are testing. And tests should be succinct and simple and declarative in what they are attempting to test in how they are named and written.

Comment: @ManoDestra have you read the comments above? I tried to explain that the test does know what it is testing. Please let me know what exactly in my question made you think that my test does not know what to test or that it is not succinct/simple/declarative?
The question is how to embed into test framework the meta information over comparison of two non-primitive type instances.

Comment: Then your question is badly worded: "JUnit assertEquals does not show which fields differ". You know which fields you're testing. If you need further meta data regarding that, then output the information via messages. If the test itself is named correctly, then the output will tell you precisely what you are testing. Internally within the test, you can ouput messages regarding specific assertions. That is the point of the message parameter in assertEquals.

Comment: @ManoDestra so you have just looked at the question header, decided that my tests are not simple, not declarative, not succinct, added your comment and voted question for closing as off-topic? That's not a good way to help others on this resource.

Comment: No, I've read the entire thing. And you can declare your assertions via the message parameter provided as part of the API. What part of that are you not comprehending? It was voted off as you have not supplied any code with your question. Different aspect. Your question is that you don't know how to get meta data regarding your assertions. You're the one asserting so declare that in your messages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118555/discussion-between-alexander-arendar-and-manodestra).

Comment: I've changed the wording as I see my original statement of the problem brought some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own assert method.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
...
public static void assertEquals(Invoice expected, Invoice actual) {
    assertEquals("invoiceDate", expected.invoiceDate, actual.invoiceDate);
    assertEquals("netPrice", expected.netPrice, actual.netPrice);
    assertEquals("invoiceRows", expected.invoiceRows, actual.invoiceRows);
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea, but it will only stumble upon the first fail and report it. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: And this is still just a more fancy way to do property checks one by one which I am trying to find some alternative for.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [assertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/). In particular:

- assertThat(expected).isEqualToComparingFieldByField(other);
- assertThat(expected).isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(other);
- assertThat(expected).isEqualToComparingOnlyGivenFields(other,"field1");
- assertThat(expected).isEqualToIgnoringNullFields(other);

Sample code:

```
@Test
public void assertJTest() {
    Invoice expected = new Invoice();
    Invoice other = new Invoice();
    expected.setInvoiceNumber("123");
    other.setInvoiceNumber("456");
    expected.setNestedSet(singleton("12345"));
    other.setNestedSet(singleton("12346"));
    assertThat(expected).isEqualToIgnoringNullFields(other);
}
```

The output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting values:
  <["123", ["12346"]]>
in fields:
  <["invoiceNumber", "nestedSet"]>
but were:
  <["456", ["12345"]]>
in <Invoice(nestedSet=[12345], invoiceNumber=123)>.
Comparison was performed on all fields
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for pointing me in AssertJ's direction.

Answer (score 1):

`Assert.assertEquals()` will call the `.equals()` method. The best solution is to roll your own:

```
public class Invoice {

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        Invoice that = (Invoice) o;
        int errors = 0;

        // compare each field one at a time
        if(!this.invoiceDate.equals(that.invoiceDate) {
            log.error(String.format("invoiceDate are not equal: expected %s, actual %s!", this.invoiceDate, that.invoiceDate)
            errors++;
        }

        // you also have the option to do something fancy, like ignore null fields:
        if(this.invoiceNumber != null && that.invoiceNumber != null) {
            if(!this.invoiceNumber.equals(that.invoiceNumber) {
                log.error(String.format("invoiceNumber are not equal: expected %s, actual %s!", this.invoiceDate, that.invoiceDate)
                errors++;
            }
        }

        // continue with all other fields ...

        return errors == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"assertEquals" doesn't know which property causes non equal result. JUnit just calls "equals" for object and checks boolean result.

If you want to know which property is different you'll need to compare properties one by one.

Or you can implement proper "toString" method and compare strings, as result you'll be able to see different objects.

Comment: I have explicitly stated that  I want to hear some advice where I would not compare properties one by one. And yes, I do know that `assertEquals` doesn't know which property causes non equal result. This is precisely why I posted this question. So I am waiting for some suggestions which other stuff/libs/techniques to use probably.

Comment: toString seems to be good idea and simple